# Reading file and search word

Tags: python

I write a python code wanting to read a text file and user can put in the word and it will print out the desire words from the text file.

Example of the text file is like this:

```
u:you
ttyl:talk to you later
l8:late
brb:be right back
lol:laughing out loud
bbl:be back later
tldr:too long; didn't read
rofl:rolling on floor laughing
gtg:got to go
```

This is my code so far:

```
dictionary = {}
file = open('abbreviations.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
count = 1
for line in lines:
    data = line.split(":")
    dictionary[data[0]] = data[1]
    print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
    count += 1

word = input("Please enter an abbreviations: ")
if dictionary.has_key(word):
  print(dictionary[word])
else:
  print(word)
```

And when I run it, it shows error in line 12 like this:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

And this is my desire output:

```
Please enter an abbreviations: u gtg

output: u got to go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading a file, you should use the `with` statement:

```
dictionary = {}

with open('abbreviations.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:                              # loop over lines in file
        word, explanation = line.split(':', 1)   # only split on the first :
        dictionary[word] = explanation.strip()   # remove final newline
```

if you want to look at the dictionary, uncomment the following lines:

```
# import json
# print(json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4))
```

Your description didn't really match your code, so I followed your description i.e. expand all the dictionary words:

```
words = input("Please enter an abbreviations: ")
for word in words.split():                          # split input into individual words
    print(dictionary.get(word, word), end=' ')
print()  # final newline
```

`dictionary.get('a', 'b')` will return `dictionary['a']` if it exists in the `dictionary`, otherwise it returns the string `'b'`.  Above I use it to return the lookup word itself if it is not in the dictionary. The `print` function normally prints a newline at the end, but we want to keep the text on a single line so I tell it to print a space at the end instead. To make things look pretty I print a newline after all the words are printed (otherwise your prompt would end up after the last character).

Output:

```
Please enter an abbreviations: u gtg
you got to go
```

**Aside:** it's not normally a good idea to create your own file format for storing data if you can use an existing one.

If you change `abbreviations.txt` to (i.e. just adding a space after the colon):

```
u: you
ttyl: talk to you later
l8: late
brb: be right back
lol: laughing out loud
bbl: be back later
tldr: too long; didn't read
rofl: rolling on floor laughing
gtg: got to go
```

makes it valid [YAML](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/yaml-tutorial-everything-you-need-get-started/) and you can use a yaml library to read the file instead. I like the [ruamel.yaml](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package (but there are others).

Then you can create `dictionary` by:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML(typ='safe')

dictionary = {}

with open('abbreviations.txt') as fp:   # see note below
    dictionary = yaml.load(fp)
```

note: renaming the file to `abbreviations.yaml` will give you syntax highlighting etc. in most editors.

Comment: Hi I understand the concept and the idea behind it thank you for that.
What if I want that to be able to handle upper and lower case at the same time? any suggestion?

Comment: It depends what you mean by handling upper/lower case... If you just want to handle mixed case in the input, the normal way is to just lowercase `word` before looking it up.

Comment: I am guessing you mean lowercase the user input if that's correct?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if dictionary.has_key(word):` with `if dictionary.get(word):`

```
if dictionary.get(word):
  print(dictionary[word])
else:
  print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

`has_key()` is deprecated and has been removed in Python 3. To check for membership, use the `in` operator:

```
if word in dictionary:
  print(dictionary[word])
else:
  print(word)
```

If you have multiple words in an input separated by space, like `u gtg`, you need to split them first. Then these two lines are all you need:

```
words = input("Please enter the abbreviations: ").split();
print(" ".join(map(lambda word: dictionary[word] if word in dictionary else word, words)))
```

Here, the words in the input will be split by space and stored in `words`. Next, I'm using the `map()` function to create another sequence from `words` where each abbreviation in `words` will be replaced by its value in the dictionary. The `map()` function will iterate through each word in `words` and call the `lambda word: dictionary[key] if word in dictionary else word`  for each word. The result will be a new sequence with all abbreviations removed. Each word in the new sequence will be joined by a space using `' '.join()`.

Finally, you must close the file using `file.close()` to release the file. Or as @thebjorn mentioned, using a context manager (`with`) is a much better option.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer, as your input is actually several words, `u` and `gtg`, you need to split the input string and check each token. Something like:

```py
words = input("Please enter an abbreviations: ")
out = []
for word in words.split():
    w = dictionary.get(word, word)  # Get word if in dict, or just return the word if not
    out.append(w)
' '.join(out)
```

then an input of `u gtg` returns:

```py
'you got to go'
```

Answer (score 0):

This little example seems to work

```
abr_file = 'abbreviations.txt'

with open(abr_file, 'rt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

abbr_dict = {}
for line in lines:
    k, v = [v.strip() for v in line.strip('\n').split(':')]
    abbr_dict[k] = v

while True:
    sentence = input('Please give me a sentence with abbreviations: ')
    words = [w.strip() for w in sentence.split()]
    full_words = []
    for word in words:
        if word in abbr_dict:
            full_words.append(abbr_dict[word])
        else:
            full_words.append(word)

    full_sentence = ' '.join(full_words)
    print(full_sentence)
```

```
Please give me a sentence with abbreviations: u gtg
you got to go
Please give me a sentence with abbreviations:
```

You just need to fix it for punctuation.